# how to test sending emails to both recipients (Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec

Here is my test which is failing at the moment :

```
describe "User request update" do
    let(:user_one) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:user_two) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:mail) { UserMailer.notify_users(user_one, user_two) }  

    it "should notify both users" do
      mail.to.should include(user_one.email)
      mail.to.should include(user_two.email)
    end
  end
```

Here is my mailer bit :

```
def notify_users(requestor, user)
    [requestor, user].each{ |u| notify_user(requestor, u) }  
  end

def notify_user(requestor, user)
  @requestor = requestor
  @user = user
  mail :to => user.email, :subject => "User requested update"
end
```

How can I test is the mail being sent to both users?

Comment: using `let(:mail)` and then `mail.to` in your test is a bad idea ... you'll be sending the notification twice in that test which isn't what you want to be testing.

Comment: @Jon that's not true. `let` memoizes the result so if you call `mail` a second time, it will just return the result without re-evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you should ensure they have different email addresses.

Assuming your factory handles that (have you seen the `Faker` gem?) then you can test what was sent in the last sent message like this:

```
# The last email sent 
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
```

You can check that the right number of messages were sent:

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count
```

So your test could look something like this:

```
describe "User request update" do
  let(:user_one) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:user_two) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  # let(:mail) { UserMailer.notify_users(user_one, user_two) } 

  # If your method sends two separate emails:
  it "#notify_users should notify both users" do
    UserMailer.notify_users(user_one, user_two)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq(2)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0].to).to include(user_one.email)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[1].to).to include(user_two.email)
  end

  # If your method sends a single email with both recipients
  it "#notify_users should notify both users" do
    UserMailer.notify_users(user_one, user_two)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to include(user_one.email)
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to include(user_two.email)
  end
end
```

You can make this a little nicer with some helper macros. Full details on how to do this are in this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

Comment: There's a slight issue here I wanted to point point out. By doing `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0]` and `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[1]`, you're coupling your tests to the order of the emails in the `deliveries` array. I'm not sure if that order can be trusted or not.